# Android:Dynamically changing the height of the image view according to the received json data

Tags: android, imageview

I am accessing a mysql database table to show the tank level .I need to display the value in an image view using a rectangle.Each time value of the level changes I need to change the height of the rectangle.How is it possible in android.In the below code container 1 and container 2 is the variable which stores the level data.How to access this data and change the height of the image view.

> package com.example.tg.mysmartcontainer;
>
> import android.os.AsyncTask; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import
>   android.widget.ListAdapter; import android.widget.ListView; import
>   android.widget.SimpleAdapter; import android.os.Handler; import
>   org.apache.http.HttpEntity; import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
>   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; import
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; import
>   org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams; import org.json.JSONArray;
>   import org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject;
>
> import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.InputStream; import
>   java.io.InputStreamReader; import java.util.ArrayList; import
>   java.util.HashMap;
>
> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>
> ```
> String myJSON;
> Handler mHandler;
> private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";
> private static final String TAG_timeStamp = "timeStamp";
> private static final String TAG_container1 = "container1";
> private static final String TAG_container2 = "container2";
>
> JSONArray container = null;
>
> ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ContainerList;
>
> ListView list;
>
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
>     ContainerList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>     final Handler handler = new Handler();
>     Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
>         @Override
>         public void run() {
>             getData();
>             handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
>         }
>     };
>     handler.postDelayed(refresh, 0);
>     //getData();
> }
>
>
> public void getData() {
>     class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
>
>         @Override
>         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
>             DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
>             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://smartgrocer.000webhostapp.com/get_data.php");
>
>             // Depends on your web service
>             httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
>
>             InputStream inputStream = null;
>             String result = null;
>             try {
>                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
>                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
>
>                 inputStream = entity.getContent();
>                 // json is UTF-8 by default
>                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
>                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
>                 String line = null;
>                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
>                     sb.append(line + "\n");
>                 }
>                 result = sb.toString();
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 // Oops
>             } finally {
>                 try {
>                     if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
>                 } catch (Exception squish) {
>                 }
>             }
>             return result;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>             myJSON = result;
>             showList();
>
>         }
>     }
>     GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
>     g.execute();
> }
>
> protected void showList() {
>     try {
>         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
>         container = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
>         if(ContainerList!=null&&ContainerList.size()>0)
>             ContainerList.clear();
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < container.length(); i++) {
>             JSONObject c = container.getJSONObject(i);
>             String timeStamp = c.getString(TAG_timeStamp);
>             String container1 = c.getString(TAG_container1);
>             String container2 = c.getString(TAG_container2);
>
>             HashMap<String, String> container = new HashMap<String, String>();
>
>             container.put(TAG_timeStamp, timeStamp);
>             container.put(TAG_container1, container1);
>             container.put(TAG_container2, container2);
>
>             ContainerList.add(container);
>         }
>
>         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
>                 MainActivity.this, ContainerList, R.layout.list_item,
>                 new String[]{TAG_timeStamp, TAG_container1, TAG_container2},
>                 new int[]{R.id.timeStamp, R.id.container1, R.id.container2}
>         );
>
>         list.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

}

Comment: yes it is possible but please provide some code so we can help

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

to set the height of the ImageView:

```
image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
```

Hope this helps.

**Important.** If you're setting the height after the layout has already been 'laid out', make sure you also call:

```
image_view.requestLayout()
```

Comment: i wanted to change the height according to the json data received.how to set it.

Comment: set that in your adapter on your imageview @tiji

Comment: how to do that..can you please edit in my code n show me..Im just a beginner in android

Comment: you cant use simpleAdapter at this position. you need to create custom adapter and set that adapter to listview. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView please go through with this link it helps

Comment: or check this http://abhiandroid.com/ui/baseadapter-tutorial-example.html this is easy for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the imageView according to the current value :

```
tankImageView.setHeight((int)(currentValue / maxValue));
```